# Importing XML to gazebo

Tags: gazebo, urdf, xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I want to import a CAD model to use it in Gazebo for simulation and control. I used the SimMechanics Link (ver. 3.1) to export it as XML from Solidworks and then tried converting it to Gazebo friendly XML using simmechanics_to_urdf package. However it doesn´t work when I spawn it showing:
GazeboROSNode SpawnModel Failure: input model_xml not Gazebo XML, or cannot be converted to Gazebo XML
I see no modifications in the original file, but I am not very familiar with XML or URDF, so I can´t tell if the convert.py is really getting the work done. Is it supposed to create a new file or modify the old one? How can I be sure that the conversion is taking place?

If anyone can help I will be very thankful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9240/importing-xml-to-gazebo/) by [Nikita](https://answers.ros.org/users/213/nikita/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-02-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The simmechanics_to_urdf package will output a URDF file to standard out (if run using the xml option, which I assume you are). You should save this to a separate file and use that as your URDF file. You may want to run it like so...

```
rosrun simmechanics_to_urdf convert.py YOUR_XML.xml YOUR_CONFIG.yaml xml > YOUR_NEW_URDF.urdf
```

...and then use YOUR_NEW_URDF.urdf when trying to spawn in Gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2011-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2